# How do I get the type of DBSet from var query in C#

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am pulling data from SQL Server, and placing it across Elastic Search, using ElasticSearchCRUD nuget. I am just into little trouble.

Could you please help out to get the type of the DBSet.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Inventories())
            {
                db.Database.Connection.Open();
                var sets =
                 from p in typeof(Inventories).GetProperties()
                 select p.Name;
//This one works if I hardcode the class name.
                var query1 = from b in db.FileSlot_39065
                             select b;
//This one gets all the class names
                var query = from b in sets
                            select b;

                foreach (var item in query1)
                {//This FileID will be populated by intellisense
                    Console.WriteLine(item.FileID);
                }

                IElasticsearchMappingResolver elasticsearchMappingResolver = new ElasticsearchMappingResolver();
                using (var elasticsearchContext = new ElasticsearchContext("http://localhost:9200/", elasticsearchMappingResolver))
                {
                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        if (item.ToString().StartsWith("FileSlot"))
                        {
                            Type itemType = item.GetType();
                            dynamic objType = item;
                            // Do not know how to get the FileID here **
                            elasticsearchContext.AddUpdateDocument(item, objType.FileID);
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        elasticsearchContext.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have a property called FileID, that is present in all my DbSet irrespective of the generic type.
My DbSets are as below

```
public DbSet<FileSlot_39065> FileSlot_39065{ get; set; }
public DbSet<FileSlot_39066> FileSlot_39066{ get; set; }
```

I am going to read all the dbsets as var sets, and then pull the data and write into Elastic Search.

Now my problem is to get the  objType.FileID, I tried converting to dynamic variable but it just does not convert to either its object type.

Could anyone please help me in getting the how to get the Class Name, and its type dynamically, that will help me in setting the right way.

Comment: `FileID` is property of one element in either `FileSlot_39065` or `FileSlot_39066` so technically you need to loop through those collections. Your second loop just loops through all property names of the DbContext. That means you need to get the collections corresponding to the name starting with `FileSlot` first before looping through the values and obtain `FileID`.

Comment: var sets? Var is just a placeholder containing any type and, as such, does not show any kind of generic behaviour (i.e., it behaves as a string when containing a string or as the Class123 when containing such a type). Bear in mind that LINQ outputs Enumerable variables rather than the original type, unless a specific conversion is performed. For example: List<int> test = new List<int>(1, 2, 3); var query = test.Where(x => x == 1); query is now a subclass of Enumerable. If I do: query = query.ToList(), I would make it a List<int>. Understand all these ideas and try to figure out what is wrong.